# Home Depot Product Page Not Showing Price Info

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have been using Selenium to web scrape HomeDepot, but the page returns NoneType for the price. When I checked, the product price box is stuck on loading, but when I use a regular browser it loads almost instantly. Here is the code I'm using

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\untitled\drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
driver.get('https://www.homedepot.ca/product/malibu-wide-plank-maple-cardiff-3-8-inch-thick-x-6-1-2-inch-wide-x-varying-length-engineered-click-hardwood-flooring-23-64-sq-ft-case-/1001341771')
time.sleep(5)
price = driver.find_element_by_class_name('hdca-product__description-pricing-price-value')
print(price.text)
```

Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 1):

Coincidentally I also scraped Home Depot's website

I used CSS selectors

```
productPrice = product.css('.price__dollars::text').getall()
```

I used scrapy, Selenium isn't necessary for this website since it isnt dynamically loaded

Comment: Thanks! I will try to web scrape again with Scrapy.

Comment: Hello, sorry to bother you but I was wondering where you learned how to use Scrapy?

Comment: @KevinW mainly just looked it up online, it's pretty straight forward most of the time since it has everything you need, selectors are probably the hardest part